# sending a satellite in the right direction

Tags: rockets, artificial-satellite

I suspect that the required accuracy of satellite velocity direction is very high. This is especially the case for low earth orbits.

The radius of the earth is 6400 km. The altitude of a low earth orbit satellite is about 400 km, which is much smaller than the radius of the earth. That is, the satellite orbit is actually a very tight one around earth, with the gap very small. Suppose we intend to put the satellite in a circular orbit, but the velocity of the satellite at release is not strictly in the tangent direction. This will result in a tilted ellipse orbit, which might touch the atmosphere at the other side of the earth.

I did not do the calculation, but it seems to me that we have to make sure the velocity of the satellite is in a very small angle.

Is the reasoning right? Does it pose any difficulty in realistic satellite launching?

Comment: I'm kind of unclear on what you're asking. Like, yeah, the velocity vector of a satellite is critical, but that's kinda the whole ball game. "How nearly can I hit the specified orbit" is the core, central question of space launches. Are you asking how accurate launches are accomplished? (That's a big question with a lot of components to it!) As written it's kind of a yes/no question, so if you can clarify what you want to learn about, I think we can give better answers.

Answer (score 4):

If the rocket is pointing the wrong way, you are having a bad problem and [you will not go to space today](https://xkcd.com/1133/).

The angle is indeed not very large, with your nice and round numbers, an object at 400km altitude can't deviate more than 3.4 degrees from the circular velocity if it wants to avoid a 6400km ball.

[image: BOOM!]

That's what an undesired radial component of 450m/s does to ya. Arguably, being *short* 450m/s instead is worse, having the perigee a thousand kilometres below ground.

So that's what all the control systems, tracking, careful planning and quality assurance is for: getting the payload pointing in the right direction with the right speed in the end.

It doesn't go right all the time, but with modern control systems any deviation from the planned launch trajectory will be corrected for in the remaining burn time of the launcher. In the early history of spaceflight, many a satellite found itself with an orbit intersecting the lithosphere.

It isn't rocket science.
Or maybe it is.

Comment: You're not wrong or anything, but the margin tightens even more when you consider that we generally intend for something in LEO to remain in a pretty tight altitude band.  Maybe the Karman line instead of the (spherical Earth?) surface is a more appropriate hard-stop?

Comment: @ErinAnne but for dramatic effect, nothing beats crashing into the surface.

Comment: @ErinAnne - You are referring to staying above the atmosphere so as to remain in orbit which is a valid point. But neither of the two "Karman" lines, either the official 100 km version or von Kármán's conceptual boundary where an airplane reaches orbital velocity, are directly related to whether an object in circular orbit will remain there for multiple orbits. Noting that von Kármán's calculations did not include whether thrust was needed to maintain orbital velocity at that altitude. A more realistic minimum would be something like 130 km where you might make it around a few times unpowered.

Answer (score 2):

> ... but the velocity of the satellite at release is not strictly in the tangent direction.

This sentence makes it sound like the release of the satellite from the launch vehicle is especially critical.   It is not.

The launch vehicle (assuming all goes well) has already delivered the satellite into the correct orbit before release.   The release imparts negligible velocity and the exact direction won't matter.

> we have to make sure the velocity of the satellite is in a very small angle.

The launch vehicle certainly has to hit the correct orbit.   But rather than trying for an impossibly small angle, the orbit is constantly changing as the engine is firing.   So in most cases, hitting the correct target will mean shutting down the engine at the correct time.